# Python Beautiful Soup - How to detect that two Tag or NavigableString objects are the same in the DOM

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I use the Beautiful Soup API to check if two Tag or NavigableString objects retrieved from the same BeautifulSoup object are really the same object in the DOM?

For example, the last line of code below evaluates to `True`, but I need the ability to detect that `first_paragraph` and `second_paragraph` are not the same object in the DOM.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example_html_str = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(example_html_str, "lxml")
paragraphs = soup.find_all("p")

first_paragraph = paragraphs[0] #First paragraph
second_paragraph = paragraphs[1] #Second paragraph

# The below evaluates to true, but they are not
# from the same part of the DOM.
print(first_paragraph == second_paragraph)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the soup object is always one object (and not the same HTML document processed via different soup objects), you should be able to do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(example_html_str, "lxml")
first_paragraph = soup.find_all("p")[0]
second_paragraph = soup.find_all("p")[1]
another_paragraph = soup.find_all("p")[0]
first_paragraph is second_paragraph
# is False
first_paragraph is another_paragraph
# is True
```

Comment: Solved, thank you! Makes sense to check if the objects are the same.

Comment: If the answer was correct, please mark it as the accepted answer (check under the vote count).